# highcharts hide xAxis

Tags: highcharts, label, config, axis

I have a bar chart displaying and I have full control over colors, alignment, data label formatting, etc, but when the chart renders there's a label below the x Axis showing "Y-values" in blue.

The generated mark-up is like so...

```
<g class="highcharts-axis" zIndex="2">
  <text x="145" y="181" 
      style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#6D869F;font-weight:bold;fill:#6D869F;" 
      zIndex="7" 
      text-anchor="middle" 
      visibility="visible">
    <tspan x="145">Y-values</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

which gives no clue as to which config value I need to overwrite.

I've spent far too long trying to figure our whether this is an attribute of the chart object or of the xAxis object or of a data series, with no luck.

In desperation I searched the source and found "Y-values" appears exactly once in highcharts.js, and seems to be the default for defaultYAxisOptions.title.text

```
ob.prototype={ defaultYAxisOptions:{ title:{ text:"Y-values" } } };
```

If I change the source to read "hello world!" then that comes out instead of Y-values, but changing the source shouldn't be necessary!

If I change my config to read...

```
               Highcharts.setOptions({
                    // lots of other settings
                    defaultYAxisOptions: {
                        title: {
                            text: "something else"
                        }
                    },
                    // some more settings
                });
```

I still get "Y-values".

Where is the correct place to assign my own value to this setting, or hide it?

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.text

Comment: But you need to hide ticks / labels or "x Axis line" as well?

Answer (score 1):

You say it is on your xAxis and it is showing "Y-values" as the text. Seems odd, yes. To remove the axis [titles](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.title) you would do something like (below is xAxis but same holds for yAxis):

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
```

I highly recommend getting familiar with the API.

Comment: Yes, this confused me a little. Even though I'm sure I'm looking at the X axis - that's the horizontal going left to right, I understand the Y axis to be vertical - this label reads "Y-values" and the only place that text appears in the source is within ob.prototype={ defaultYAxisOptions:{ title:{ text:"Y-values" } } };

Comment: @BrianLowe, if you could create a jsFiddle reproducing this issue with your code and some representative data that would help. It may be that you have your axis inverted - but without seeing your highcharts code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: if it is a horizontal bar chart, the x and y axes switch places, as they should.

Comment: @jlbriggs, correct. I meant that he might have flipped them and not known but saw the label where he thought he shouldn't have been.